# Python 2 or 3 circular import clarification

Tags: python, import

I know this question has been asked/answered a lot, but I'm curious about my specific case -- and I haven't seen an answer that I fully understand.

Is it bad to have several modules that import the same module? So, say I have some generic utilities module that I reuse a lot, and modulex.py and moduley.py both import it. But then say modulex needs to import moduley. At this point, am I introducing bad juju?

Comment: No, that's entirely normal unless you have something in your module-level code that has side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only bad to multiply import module `M` from modules `N1`, `N2`, `N3` etc if `M` holds some global state that is then modified by some of the `N*` modules. Then, side effects occur depending on import order.

Usually in clean code, this is not the case, and if you only hold class definitions and functions, as well as global vars that are not modified/modifyable, then you should be completely fine.

Comment: What if module M has a class variable that is modified by modules that import it? Or is that what you meant by "only hold class definitions and functions"?

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of case this answer describes as "if `M` holds some global state" - in general designing your modules so that they have mutable module-level variables is a bad idea for exactly this reason. There are special situations where it makes sense, but you should steer clear of them unless you're sure you know what you're doing. While it's not exactly holding mutable variables, the built-in `logger` module could be a starting point for thinking about when you might want to share module-level state across multiple imports.